# How to get access of IPA file in "Pending Developer Release" state?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ipa

One of my iOS app is in **"Pending Developer Release"** state in **App Store Connect**. Its been a long time (around 3 months) it got approved. Now this ipa file is removed from testFlight. can anyone let me know please the way to get access of this ipa file in App Store Connect? I need to check something in app before **"Release this version"**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

that is currently not supported. You could only submit a new build, which would be available in TestFLight for the next 90 days.

Answer (score 0):

It was never possible to download the IPA file you uploaded to App Store Connect from Apple. Make sure to store your source code and possibly IPA files in source control (e.g. GitHub, Bitbucket or similar).

As already stated TestFlight builds are available for testing for a 90 days period, but this has nothing to do with how long Apple "stores" the build. In fact you can select any uploaded build for a version and submit it for review. The TestFlight time limit is just for security purpose, so that there is no alternative way to distribute apps.